# ZF2 How to use pages javascripts and stylesheets in layout

Tags: javascript, css, zend-framework, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I use zend framework 2.

This is my layout.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html class="fixed" lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php echo $this->headTitle('Test') ?>

    <?php

        /* Vendor CSS */
        $this->headLink(array(
                'rel' => 'shortcut icon',
                'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
                'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'
            ))
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'aaaa.css')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'bbbb.css');


        /* Specific Page Vendor CSS */
        $this->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'cccc.css')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'dddd.css')

        /* Theme CSS */
        $this->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'eeee.css');       
    ?>

</head>
<body>

<section class="body">

    <?php print $this->render('layout/header') ?>

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <?php print $this->render('layout/left-menu') ?>

        <section role="main" class="content-body">
            <?php echo $this->content; ?>
        </section>
    </div>

    <?php print $this->render('layout/right-menu') ?>
</section>

<?php
    /* Vendor */
    $this->headScript()
            ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'aaaa.js')
            ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'bbbb.js');          

    /* Specific Page Vendor */
    $this->headScript()
        ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'cccc.js')
        ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'dddd.js);

    /* Theme Base, Components and Settings */
    $this->headScript()
        ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'eeee.js');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This layout is working fine. But Specific Page vendors are not need set in layout.phtml. It will change with content. So i need move /* Specific Page Vendor */ part to related .phtml file. After that My layout and content should be like this.

layout.phtml
    doctype(); ?>

```
    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php echo $this->headTitle('Test') ?>

    <?php

        /* Vendor CSS */
        $this->headLink(array(
                'rel' => 'shortcut icon',
                'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
                'href' => $this->basePath() . '/img/favicon.ico'
            ))
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'aaaa.css')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'bbbb.css');

        /* Theme CSS */
        $this->headLink()
            ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'eeee.css');       
    ?>

</head>
<body>

<section class="body">

    <?php print $this->render('layout/header') ?>

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <?php print $this->render('layout/left-menu') ?>

        <section role="main" class="content-body">
            <?php echo $this->content; ?>
        </section>
    </div>

    <?php print $this->render('layout/right-menu') ?>
</section>

<?php
    /* Vendor */
    $this->headScript()
            ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'aaaa.js')
            ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'bbbb.js');  

    /* Theme Base, Components and Settings */
    $this->headScript()
        ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'eeee.js');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Content.phtml

```
/* Specific Page Vendor CSS */
$this->headLink()
    ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'cccc.css')
    ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath() . 'dddd.css')

<h1>This is content of the page</h1>

/* Specific Page Vendor */
$this->headScript()
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'cccc.js')
    ->appendFile($this->basePath() . 'dddd.js);
```

Please assume bottom stylesheets are override above stylesheets. bottom javascript use above javascript functions.

How can i do it?

Comment: What? and why is it duplicated?

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is. You say you need to move some of your headscripts to the related .phtml file - did you try this? It should work fine.

Comment: Do you want use different layouts for different pages?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep layout files and page files apart. Layout JS / CSS are files that you need on EVERY page.

Content styling / javascript files always load from the controller actions.

```
$api->getView()->inlineScript()->appendScript('assets/js/jsfile.js');
$api->getView()->headLink()->appendStylesheet('assets/css/cssfile.css')
```

Comment: i need add cccc.js, dddd.js into bbbb.js and eeee.js. it is not append.